# Problem with unit tests: Junit and the Mockito framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I am learning to do unit and double tests with Junit and the Mockito framework, but I am not getting the expected result in a specific test with 'mocks'. I do an `assertThat` that should return positive test, instead, it returns an error that says `Mockito cannot mock this class`. It is a class called 'Console' that must print and collect values ​​from the user's keyboard, but of course, in unit tests this should be 'mocked' to avoid 'intervening test' in antipattern, where the test asks for data to the developer, that is, I need to 'mock up' a user input. This 'Console' class is like a small facade of the typical java BufferedReader class.

I pass you the classes involved:

Console:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Console {

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public String readString(String title) {
        String input = null;
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            this.write(title);
            try {
                input = this.bufferedReader.readLine();
                ok = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.writeError("characte string");
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return input;
    }

    public int readInt(String title) {
        int input = 0;
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            try {
                input = Integer.parseInt(this.readString(title));
                ok = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.writeError("integer");
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return input;
    }

    public char readChar(String title) {
        char charValue = ' ';
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            String input = this.readString(title);
            if (input.length() != 1) {
                this.writeError("character");
            } else {
                charValue = input.charAt(0);
                ok = true;
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return charValue;
    }

    public void writeln() {
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void write(String string) {
        System.out.print(string);
    }

    public void writeln(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public void write(char character) {
        System.out.print(character);
    }

    public void writeln(int integer) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

    private void writeError(String format) {
        System.out.println("FORMAT ERROR! " + "Enter a " + format + " formatted value.");
    }
}
```

ConsoleTest:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

public class ConsoleTest {

    @Mock
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    @InjectMocks
    private Console console;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before(){
        initMocks(this);
        //this.console = new Console();
    }
    @Test
    public void givenConsoleWhenReadStringThenValue() throws IOException {
        String string = "yes";
        when(this.bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(string);
        assertThat(this.console.readString("title"), is(string));
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>

    </modules>

    <artifactId>solution.java.swing.socket.sql</artifactId>
    <groupId>usantatecla.tictactoe</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks and greetings to the community!

Comment: Hi, but why you need it `this.console = new Console();`  in `before()` method?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, but If I comment that line, it gives an error anyway

Comment: There are some fundamental problems. You cannot mock an object you create inside the sut by new. You could inject it, or you could use a factory to create it and then mock the factory. And I do not see, how you are creating Console.

Comment: I tried your code and it works with commented `this.console = new Console();` and added `junit-vintage-engine` lib.

Comment: I tried your code and it works in simple spring-boot project version `2.4.1`. Also I used `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of your `@BeforeEach` method.

Comment: Yeah, your `this.console = new Console();` is overwriting the one with the mock injected.

Comment: Thanks people for the answers. I have tried the option to mport the library 'junit-vintage-...', but it keeps giving me the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

I personally am not a huge fun of Mockito, I prefer to have full control of my classes using an interface and two implementations (one for production and one for test).

So this doesn't respond directly to your question about Mockito but it allows you to perfectly control the behaviour of your code without the need to use another framework.

You may define a very simple interface:

```
public interface Reader {
    String readLine();
}
```

Then, you use that interface in your class Console:

```
public class Console {
    private final Reader reader;

    public Console(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    
    //Replace all your this.bufferedReader.readLine() by this.reader.readLine();
   
}
```

So, in your production code you can use the real implementation with the Buffered reader:

```
public class ProductionReader implements Reader {
    
    private final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(...);

    @Override
    public String readLine() {
        this.bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
     
}
```

---

```
Console console = new Console(new ProductionReader());
```

... While in your tests you can use a test implementation:

```
public class TestReader implements Reader {
    @Override
    public String readLine() {
        return "Yes";
    }
}
```

---

```
Console console = new Console(new TestReader());
```

Note that while in your specific case you may mock the behaviour using Mockito, there are a lot of other cases when you will need a more complex approach and the a ove will allow you to have full control and full debuggability of your code without the need of adding any dependency.

Comment: thanks Matteo for the choice, it looks good. The problem is that I do not want to modify the SUT (subject under test), or, if necessary, do it the minimum.  Another aspect is that if there are many DOC's (Depended On Component), you would have to modify the SUT too much.

Comment: This is just re-inventing what Mockito can do for you automatically.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem i have been in front of many situations where Mockito couldn't respond to our needs. Plus, Mockito can be obscure (you don't really see and control what happens behind the stubs). To conclude, I have seen this technique applied way too many times to classify it as simply "just re-inventing", it is a well known and spread design, not something that I invented out of nowhere ;)

Comment: Interesting answer. Anyway and off topic already but if library fulfills only 98% of your needs is it a reason to dump it and make everything by yourself instead of that missing 2%? And from the other point of view: libraries like Mockito can direct you to make code more testable instead of sticking to designs that require "solution per class".

Comment: @pirho in my experience is way more than 2%. I'd say 50%. Also, it is a very spread design (not only java, largely used in C++ for example), nothing I invented or took out of my pocket. So far it has always been more convenient to me, and I've been using Mockito for years before changing to this point of view.  But yes, it's off-topic, I just wanted to share _one way_ to do it, because frankly when I was using Mockito I was spending a lot of time understanding what the framework was doing and how (hard to debug and I don't even tell you what happened when we upgraded mockito version :)

Comment: Just to make clear I was not blaming anyone for any "vain" inventions just wondering the extra work. And been there also with some "cryptic" libraries but for me Mockito has been suitable. Think that for some legacy code projects it might be hard to make tests if there are lots of Mockito "incompliant" code that is risky to change. Anyway, just to stress if it is not easily testable with Mockito first thing that occurs to my mind is that what should I refactor in my code to get it testable.